# prototype odd result when changing way to define

Tags: javascript, prototype

When trying to test prototype functionality, I got this odd result:
Here is my first test:

```
<script>
function Hello() {
}
var a = new Hello();

Hello.prototype.name = "Fred";
alert(a.name);
</script>
```

And, here's the second one:

```
<script>
function Hello() {
}
var a = new Hello();

Hello.prototype = {
        name : "Fred",
}
alert(a.name);
</script>
```

I can't understand why the first will return a alert with "Fred" and the second is "undefined" though these mean the same thing?
Could you help me with it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two code snippets are not actually equal.

In the first script you only override `Hello.prototype.name`, while in the second script you override the whole content of `Hello.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function in JavaScript, the interpreter makes a special `prototype` property available on the function, which points to an object, in case you use that function as a constructor. The `[[Prototype]]` internal property points to this object when you create a new object using the constructor.

When you replace the `prototype` property with a new one, you are replacing that reference, and if you do it after you *instantiate* an object, you will find the `prototype` object appears to be *stale* (that object's `[[Prototype]]` is pointing to the original object that `prototype` pointed to).

#### Solutions

Only assign new properties directly on the `prototype` property.

```
var constructor = function() { };
constructor.prototype.someMethod = function() { };
```

Use an *extend* type function to extend the existing `prototype` property with your new object (in this example, I used Underscore's [`extend()`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function).

```
var constructor = function() { };
_.extend(constructor.prototype, { someMethod: function() { } });
```

Make sure after the constructor, assigning the `prototype` property is the very next step in your program (generally not recommended).

```
var constructor = function() { };
constructor.prototype = { someMethod: function() { } };
```

Comment: wow, you're my hero Alex. Deadly simple, super easy to understand. Thank soooooooooooooooo much!

Answer (score 1):

Your ordering is messed up. You need assign the object to the prototype *before* using the `new` operator:

```
function Hello() {
}

Hello.prototype = {
        name : "Fred",
}

var a = new Hello();
alert(a.name);​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/9E9jn/)